# Best way to store time ranges with intersection constraint?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to implement timetable, with business hours. What is the best way to store time ranges (e.g. 12:00-14:00) from lower bound to upper (24h), with intersection check, eg for **object_id** = 1 and **day_of_the_week** = 1, there can not be intersections in any provided intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [Exclusion Constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION):

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (object_id WITH =, day_of_the_week WITH =, time_range WITH &&)
```